# Delay specific values

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have a motionSensor, which offers me a `Subject` with a `boolean` value. `true`, when movement was detected and `false` when the sensor doesn't detect anything after a fixed, non-changeable timerange.

I want to turn lights on movement, but the lights should stay on for a given period. `false` should be delayed.

If a `true`-value was emitted, while the delay is "delaying", then nothing should happen (aka the lights should stay on).

Consider this table

| time t | emitted value | action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | turn lights on |
| 2 | false | do nothing |
| 3 | none emitted | turn lights off |
| 4 | true | turn lights on |
| 5 | false | do nothing |
| 6 | true | do nothing |

Here is some pseudo-code:

```java
motionSensor.isMoving$()
    // delayWhen-method does not exsit
    .delayWhen(Duration.of(5, MINUTES), isMoving -> !isMoving)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(isMoving -> {
        if (isMoving) {
            turnLightsOn();
        } else {
            turnLightsOff();
        });
```

I need it in this [Github Project](https://github.com/AndreKoepke/home-system/blob/fae1ecf1b1faa4db3e6f4f4f17e4a40da3cffbe1/src/main/java/ch/akop/homesystem/message/MotionSensorReactor.java#L33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no operator, so I wrote it as a manual style.

```java
Subject<Boolean> isMoving$ = getSubject();

isMoving$
    .switchMap(value -> isMoving 
        ? Observable.just(isMoving) 
        : Observable.just(isMoving).delay(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .subscribe(isMoving -> isMoving ? turnLightsOn() : turnLightsOff());
```

Special note: IntelliJ is confused by this code. If it warns you, you can ignore it.
[image: Image of IntelliJ warning]